# Changing Java Swing themes on runtime causes JTable bugs

Tags: java, windows, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I want to change look & feels on runtime in my `Java` `Swing` GUI.

For that I'm calling `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` and `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI()` to refresh the GUI which seems to work but the latter method causes a severe GUI bug: Any tab with a `JTable` in it causes the following exception and fail to render properly:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTableHeaderUI$XPDefaultRenderer.paint(WindowsTableHeaderUI.java:171)
    at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paintCell(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:710)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paint(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:652)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableHeaderUI.paint(SynthTableHeaderUI.java:173)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableHeaderUI.update(SynthTableHeaderUI.java:144)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1042)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1978)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3906)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch$$$capture(InvocationEvent.java:311)
```

It gives a "ghosting" effect of rendering items only when the mouse is moved over them and it's unusable.

A Java bug for this has already been reported [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6429812). I'm running Java version `1.8.0_231`. Is there a way to fix this problem or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
private static void setHeaderAlignment(JTable table)
{
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    HeaderRenderer headerRenderer = new HeaderRenderer(table);
    header.setDefaultRenderer(headerRenderer);
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Yes and it doesn't fix this issue

Comment: Good. Always worth verifying

Comment: *or maybe I'm doing something wrong?* - hard to tell since you didn't post an [mre]. The bug indicates this is a problem when using a custom header render. Don't know what you are doing. The code in [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) uses default renderers and doesn't have an issue, but it only changes the LAF, not a theme.

Comment: @camickr: Yes, I'm setting a custom header renderer, I added the code snippet.

Comment: A "code snippet" is not an "MRE". All I can suggest is to 1) replace the renderer with the default renderer. 2) do the LAF change 3) reset the renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not setting a default renderer fixes the bug. It appears as if I don't need the header renderer at all so I'm happy with dropping it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because your `JTableHeader header` is a local variable of your static method.

Try extracting it as a class property in your class and set it at some time to your JTable. Then call your static method.

It will provide access to that property before trying to set its own default renderer.